# facebook open graph doesn't show picture and titel anymore, it worked yesterday

Tags: facebook

Is anyone having problems with sharing a link on facebook? I do this al the time (www.facebook.com/rallylovers). I copy the URL of new articles (site www.rallylovers.be) and copy them on my facebook account. Until yesterdag everything worked well... 
I get the right picture with the article, ... But today it stopped working ??? The strange thing is other sites won't work as well. I tried www.hln.be the biggest news-site here in Belgium and some articles didn't work.
The onlything I see on facebook is the link to my homepage, no tekst, no image and no exact title...

Answer (score 0):

Facebook is currently having problems with the **scraper** for european accounts. (accounts in america seem to be working just fine).

Comment: Hey Raphael, can you point to some more information about this?

Comment: @SeanKinsey, I stumbled upon this issue today and tested it with 6 different accounts.3 portuguese accounts, 2 brazilian and 1 from the US. The scrapper worked fine for the accounts which were registered in the americas.

Comment: I also tested using the Open Graph debugger and the european accounts all got an error when trying to fetch the website for scrapping. The error was: "Curl Error: COULDNT_CONNECT"

Comment: What is interesting is that what seemed to matter was where the account had been registered. I created my account in Brazil but I live in Portugal, and I could fetch the website for scrapping with no problem at all. The scrapper was also successful for an american friend who works with me here.

Comment: I took screen shots of everything in case it helps.

Comment: Thanks, this actually helps a lot! Would you mind giving me the id of one of the accounts that works and one that doesn't?

Comment: @SeanKinsey, It works for this id: 100000999724968 and it doesn't work for this one: 529893471

Comment: Based on the data provided here, we were able to correctly deduce what was going on, and a fix is in the works. Thanks!

Comment: @SeanKinsey, not sure if this is related but I am having trouble using the API explorer. No matter which method I try, I get the same error: {
  "error": {
    "type": "http", 
    "message": "unknown error", 
    "status": 0
  }
}